# C/C++ Vector and reference parameter

Tags: c++, vector, parameters, reference

I want to receive a VECTOR in my main function. The code is this.

```
int myfunction(void);


int main(){

    int p = myfunction(void);
    std::cout << p[2] << std::endl;

};


int myfunction(void){
      int new array[4]={0,1111,2222,3333};
      int *p;
      p = array;
      return p; 
};
```

Comment: You cannot receive any other than the pre-defined `int argc, char* argv[]` parameters at your `main()` function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think he wants `myfunction` to return an array/vector to main.

Comment: @tux3 Aw, let me play possum a bit with him :(. You're going to spoil my afternoon.

Comment: I'm going to ruin your fun with my serious CW answer!

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you would do:

```
std::vector<int> myfunction();

int main(){
    std::vector<int> p = myfunction();
    std::cout << p[2] << std::endl;
}

std::vector<int> myfunction(){
    return std::vector<int>{0,1111,2222,3333};
}
```

And in C you could do:

```
int* myfunction(void);

int main(void){
    int* p = myfunction();
    printf("%d\n", p[2]);
    free(p);
}

int* myfunction(void){
    int tmp[] = {0,1111,2222,3333};
    int* array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(tmp));
    memcpy(array, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
    return array;
}
```

Now if you have trouble with this code, I'd recommend you go pick a good C or C++ book (whichever it is you're interested in) and read up on the basics of the language, because you seem really confused.